# How does blockchain work on a mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum

I have been going through some lessons on blockchain and am curious as to how mobile apps utilise blockchains.

From my understanding, each account will have to continously mine the network to get the latest information. However, aren't blockchains massive ledgers that have to be downloaded each time a new user joins or each time an update is made? How does this get stored on the mobile device?

Someone mentioned that they used REST API to communicate with their own account node itself. Is this the only way to make it work?

How do apps like Coinbase work?

Sorry for the long question. Was hoping to get some clarification on this technology.

Comment: Android blockchain provide guides and tutorial, have look this https://blog.blockchain.com/category/tutorials-and-guides/

Answer (score 0):

Currently I don't know any real node running from android maybe in the future this can be a possibility but for now, from your phone, you can only conduct `[JSON-RPC][1]` `GET` most likely through javascript using `web3.js`. 
These requests are sent to real Blockchain nodes Parity, Geth and these will run all the needed calculations and return a response.

Coinbase is a classical Backend service, they are connected to many nodes but from your point as an android user, you send a request to there API their backend handles all web3.js transactions and returns a response.

So can you connect with the blockchain directly from your phone? No maybe in the future.

Can you use web3.js now and get information and send requests? yes

Do you do this when you use coinbase app? no